# Numpy zip function

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

If I have two numpy 1D arrays, for example

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])
y=np.array([11,22,33])
```

How can I zip these into Numpy 2D coordinates arrays?
If I do:

```
x1,x2,x3=zip(*(x,y))
```

The results are of type list, not Numpy arrays. So I have do

```
x1=np.asarray(x1)
```

and so on..
Is there a simpler method, where I do not need to call `np.asarray` on each coordinate?
Is there a Numpy zip function that returns Numpy arrays?

Comment: np.array([(a,b) for a, b in zip(*(x, y))])

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use

```
x1, x2, x3 = np.vstack([x,y]).T
```

Comment: I found `np.stack` to be more versatile. It is the solution for stacking n-dimensional input arrays.

Comment: You can now also simply use `np.column_stack((x,y))` or `np.stack((x,y), axis=1)`. I don't know if the `.T` transpose in this statement is somehow optimized, so it might add unnecessary computation. Either way, my suggestion is to use these helper functions and it makes for cleaner code too.

Answer (score 3):

Stack the input arrays depth-wise using [`numpy.dstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and get rid of the singleton dimension using [`numpy.squeeze()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) and then assign the result to co-ordinate variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` as in:

```
In [84]: x1, x2, x3 = np.squeeze(np.dstack((x,y)))

# outputs
In [85]: x1
Out[85]: array([ 1, 11])

In [86]: x2
Out[86]: array([ 2, 22])

In [87]: x3
Out[87]: array([ 3, 33])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
x1, x2, x3 = np.c_[x, y]
```

Output:

```
# x1
array([ 1, 11])

# x2
array([ 2, 22])

# x3
array([ 3, 33])
```